# SCRIPT10: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available in IE for my sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, internet-explorer

I am getting this error in IE for my sharepoint online site

SCRIPT10: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

File: suiteserviceproxyiframe_20c14355.js, Line: 2474, Column: 14406